# Call to a member function whereHas() on a non-object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

In my controller I have wrote this following code

```
$usersCount       = User::where('activated', '=', 1)->where('group_id', '=', 1)->where('availability_date', '<=', $opportunity_date)->count();
                $locations_array_result = explode(",",$locations_array_result);
                foreach ($locations_array_result as $param)
                {
                    $usersCount = $usersCount->whereHas('location', function($q) use($param){
                        $q->where('location_id', '=', $param );
                    });
                }
```

This code giving following error 
Call to a member function whereHas() on a non-object
Can anyone help me to find out what i have done wrong!!!

Answer (score 0):

`$usersCount` is already a number from the 1st line of your sample.

You want instead to replace `$usersCount->whereHas` with `User::whereHas` in your foreach loop.

Comment: But i need also above condition and total number of records then what is will be query. I am newbee in laravel. If you can please help me

Comment: This will solve the issue but I don't think it's the result he has in mind, of course there's not much more you can suggest without further info. I am guessing the required result is get users with first query requirements + having any of the location array ids? in which case, a whereIn('field', array) at the first query would suffice EDIT: @RITESHNAG provide more info on the desired result and your structure

Comment: I have 3 tables one is user_location with columns [id,location_id,user_id], user table with columns [id,...] and location with columns[id,name]
In $locations_array_result I have the location id and I have to count total number of users who are from those locations.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a very wild guess here, I would think you need to get all users with these requirements

```
 ->where('group_id', '=', 1)->where('availability_date', '<=', $opportunity_date)
```

plus having a location_id value which exists on an array named $locations_array_result

If this is the case, this is all you need:

```
User::where('activated', '=', 1)->where('group_id', '=', 1)->where('availability_date', '<=', $opportunity_date)->whereIn('location_id', $locations_array_result)->get();
```

EDIT
Following your comment below, I assume user has many to many relation with locations (defined in your model), so [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading) and then using a condition with a callback should do the job:

```
 $users = User::where('activated', '=', 1)
  ->where('group_id', '=', 1)
  ->where('availability_date', '<=', $opportunity_date)
  ->with(array('location' => function($query) use ($locations_array_result)
  {
    $query->whereIn('location_id', $locations_array_result); 
   }))->get();
```

Comment: Thanks but here location_id coming from another table may be multiple locations selected by an user and that's why multiple rows are there in user_location table

Comment: I have 3 tables one is user_location with columns [id,location_id,user_id], user table with columns [id,name,availability_date,group_id,activated] and location with columns[id,name] In $locations_array_result I have the location id and I have to count total number of users who are from those locations in $locations_array_result.
What will be the query for this type of filtering?? @alou