# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::whereHas() in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm having issues with the following piece of code on my controller:

```
$opportunity_date = $oppr_arr->opportunity_date;
$locations_array_result = explode(",",$locations_array_result);
$usersCount = User::where('activated', '=', 1)
                  ->where('group_id', '=', 1)
                  ->where('availability_date', '<=', $opportunity_date)
                  ->get();

foreach ($locations_array_result as $param) {
    $usersCount = $usersCount->whereHas('desiredLocation', function ($q) use($param) {
        $q->where('location_id', '=', $param );
    });
}

$usersCount = $usersCount->count();
```

When I run it, it gives me the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::whereHas()
```

I have my relationships set up like this:

**User Model**

```
public function desiredLocation()  {
     return $this->belongsToMany('Location', 'user_desired_location');
}
```

**Location Model**

```
class Location extends \Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'locations';
    protected $fillable = array('name');

    public function country() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Country');
    }
}
```

And the database structure for `user_desired_location` table is:

```
- id
- user_id
- location_id
```

Comment: You are executing the query, when you call the `get()` method of the QueryBuilder in your controller. That means `$usersCount` is of type `Collection`, meaning in turn you can't call `whereHas` on it (`whereHas` is a QueryBuilder's method). I don't quite understand what you're trying to do, but you need to change your code :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call to a member function whereHas() on a non-object in laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26994459/call-to-a-member-function-wherehas-on-a-non-object-in-laravel)

Answer (score 6):

You're calling `get` too early and this is running the query before you wanted to. Moving it after the `foreach` loop solves it:

```
$usersCount = User::where('activated', '=', 1)
                  ->where('group_id', '=', 1)
                  ->where('availability_date', '<=', $opportunity_date);

foreach ($locations_array_result as $param) {
    $usersCount = $usersCount->whereHas('desiredLocation', function($q) use($param){
        $q->where('location_id', '=', $param );
    });
}

$users = $usersCount->get();
$usersCount = $users->count();
```

Also note: If all you're interested in is the count and you won't be using the actual users, you don't need to call `get` and then `count`; this generates unnecessary load by actually fetching all users and counting it on PHP side. Instead, use `count` directly and Eloquent will issue a `COUNT()` query, doing it on the database side. Like so:

```
$usersCount = $usersCount->count();
```